Postgres graph query gets slow because of a nested loop join
Context
I am using postgres as a multi-tenant graph database.
All data is stored in a single table, and I rely on partial indexes to make queries efficient.
Here's how a minimal schema looks:
CREATE TABLE triples (
    app_id text NOT NULL,
    entity_id text NOT NULL,
    attr_id text NOT NULL,
    value jsonb NOT NULL,
    eav boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    ave boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    vae boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    created_at bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    checked_data_type text
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION triples_extract_number_value(value jsonb)
RETURNS double precision AS $$
BEGIN
  IF jsonb_typeof(value) = 'number' THEN
    RETURN value::double precision;
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX vae_idx ON triples (app_id, value, attr_id, entity_id) WHERE vae;

CREATE INDEX ave_number_idx ON triples (app_id, attr_id, triples_extract_number_value(value), entity_id) WHERE ave AND checked_data_type = 'number';


In an app with conversations, groups, and messages, data could be stored as:
{app_id: 'app_1', entity_id: 'convo_1', attr_id: 'title': "My Conversation"} 
{app_id: 'app_1', entity_id: 'group_1', attr_id: 'title': "My Group"} 
{app_id: 'app_1', entity_id: 'convo_1', attr_id: 'group': "'group_1'", vae: true} // this 'links' convos to groups
{app_id: 'app_1', entity_id: 'msg_1', attr_id: 'time': "123", ave: true, checked_data_type: 'number'} // this indexes our 'time' field  
{app_id: 'app_1', entity_id: 'msg_1', attr_id: 'convo': "'convo_1'", vae: true} // this  links `msg_1` to `convo_1`

Goal
I want to satisfy the following query:

"Give me all convos, which belong to group 'group-1', and have a message who's time is greater than 5."

To do this, I wrote the following query, which does 3 self-joins:
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(match_0_0.entity_id)
FROM 
    triples AS match_0_0
JOIN 
    triples AS match_0_1
    ON match_0_1.app_id = match_0_0.app_id
    AND match_0_1.vae = true
    AND match_0_1.attr_id = 'convo'
    AND match_0_1.value = to_jsonb(match_0_0.entity_id)
JOIN 
    triples AS match_0_2
    ON match_0_2.app_id = match_0_1.app_id
    AND match_0_2.ave = true
    AND match_0_2.attr_id = 'time'
    AND triples_extract_number_value(match_0_2.value) >= 5
    AND match_0_2.checked_data_type = 'number'
    AND match_0_2.entity_id = match_0_1.entity_id
WHERE 
    match_0_0.app_id = 'chat_app'
    AND match_0_0.vae = true
    AND match_0_0.attr_id = 'groups'
    AND match_0_0.value = '"group_1"';

Problem
The problem is, this query takes about 14 seconds to satisfy. Running with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), shows:



QUERY PLAN




Unique  (cost=1.10..51.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.588..14786.024 rows=150 loops=1)


Buffers: shared hit=523495


->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.10..51.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.588..14784.589 rows=5996 loops=1)


Buffers: shared hit=523495


->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.82..37.31 rows=4 width=25) (actual time=0.048..29.058 rows=12000 loops=1)


Buffers: shared hit=1499


->  Index Only Scan using vae_idx on triples match_0_0  (cost=0.41..11.98 rows=3 width=17) (actual time=0.029..0.533 rows=300 loops=1)


Index Cond: ((app_id = 'chat_app'::text) AND (value = '"group_1"'::jsonb) AND (attr_id = 'groups'::text))


Heap Fetches: 300


Buffers: shared hit=55


->  Index Only Scan using vae_idx on triples match_0_1  (cost=0.41..8.44 rows=1 width=34) (actual time=0.016..0.079 rows=40 loops=300)


Index Cond: ((app_id = 'chat_app'::text) AND (value = to_jsonb(match_0_0.entity_id)) AND (attr_id = 'convo'::text))


Heap Fetches: 12000


Buffers: shared hit=1444


->  Index Scan using ave_number_idx on triples match_0_2  (cost=0.28..3.64 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.929..1.229 rows=0 loops=12000)


Index Cond: ((app_id = 'chat_app'::text) AND (attr_id = 'time'::text) AND (triples_extract_number_value(value) >= '5'::double precision) AND (entity_id = match_0_1.entity_id))


Buffers: shared hit=521996


Planning:


Buffers: shared hit=109


Planning Time: 0.477 ms


Execution Time: 14786.197 ms



Nested Loop
Looking at EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), I noticed that the nested_loop join has lots of buffer hits.
If I try disabling nested loop joins, the query resolves in 40 ms:
SET enable_nestloop TO off;

SELECT 
    DISTINCT(match_0_0.entity_id)
FROM 
    triples AS match_0_0
JOIN 
    triples AS match_0_1
    ON match_0_1.app_id = match_0_0.app_id
    AND match_0_1.vae = true
    AND match_0_1.attr_id = 'convo'
    AND match_0_1.value = to_jsonb(match_0_0.entity_id)
JOIN 
    triples AS match_0_2
    ON match_0_2.app_id = match_0_1.app_id
    AND match_0_2.ave = true
    AND match_0_2.attr_id = 'time'
    AND triples_extract_number_value(match_0_2.value) >= 5
    AND match_0_2.checked_data_type = 'number'
    AND match_0_2.entity_id = match_0_1.entity_id
WHERE 
    match_0_0.app_id = 'chat_app'
    AND match_0_0.vae = true
    AND match_0_0.attr_id = 'groups'
    AND match_0_0.value = '"group_1"';

Question
Is there a way I can hint to postgres, so it chooses a better strategy?
Repro
I set up a repro on DB Fiddle, which shows the slow query:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/15620

There were a few ways we discovered to hint to Postgres that a nested loop join was a bad idea here.
Option 1: Make nested_loop more expensive
If we adjusted some PG parameters:
SET random_page_cost = 2.0;
SET cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.05;
SET cpu_operator_cost = 0.0001;

Then PG would use a hash join for this query.
We ran a backtest on other queries though, and this resulted in poorer performance overall.
Option 2: Add an index where entity_id comes before value
If we made an index where entity_id came before value, Postgres would switch to a hash join and use it:
CREATE INDEX aev_number_idx ON triples (app_id, attr_id, entity_id, triples_extract_number_value(value)) WHERE ave AND checked_data_type = 'number';

However, this didn't feel right to us.
We couldn't delete the ave_number_idx, as there are scenarios where we want to use value, to find entity_id.
This means we would have to dupe our data on this new index.
Option 3: Remove entity_id from ave_number_idx
The final option, was to remove entity_id in ave_number_idx.
CREATE INDEX ave_number_idx_no_e ON triples (app_id, attr_id, triples_extract_number_value(value)) WHERE ave AND checked_data_type = 'number';

This forced Postgres to do hash joins. Running a backtest, we didn't see any queries get slower.
We ended up choosing Option 3.
More alternatives
One method we tried was to re-write the query as materialized CTEs. However, this only sporradically worked. Some ways that we wrote the CTE would cause a hash join, and some ways would not.
We tried using extended statistics too, but were not able to create a statistic that told postgres this nested loop join was a bad idea.

Hi Stepan, you are allowed to tick your own answer after 24 hrs.
